# React render Chart.js based on api response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am using reacts and chart.js, and the chart-js/react wrapper. I am dynamically pulling the data from an API and then basing the chart on the data returned. The issue is that it is only one name from the API call that is being displayed in the graph. There should be three names.

I think the problem is that the rendering of the `Graph` component is being rendered before all the data has been returned by the API, so the graph only contains the first name. At least this is what i think. I have tried working with the `componentWillMount` function but cannot get it working.

can anyone spot anything wrong with my code below?

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            names: []
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            this.setState({ names: data })
        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Graph names={this.state.names}/>               
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Graph = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.props.names.length; i++) {
            names.push(this.props.names[i].name)
        }
        var chartData =  {
            labels: names,
            datasets: [{
                   data: goals
                },
                {
                    data: predictions
                }]
        };
        return <LineChart data={chartData} width="600" height="250"/>
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to control your state like below:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            names: [],
            isLoaded: false
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            this.setState({ 
                names: data,
                isLoaded: true
            })
        }.bind(this));
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.isLoaded ? <Graph names={this.state.names}/> : <div>Still Loading... </div> }
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

So once you get all your data you can render your chart otherwise show the loading screen. Take a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192621/reactjs-async-rendering-of-components) probably it will be helpfull for you. Hope it makes sense for you.

Comment: The problem now is that the graph is getting rendered twice.

Comment: @phantom that's okay. - once when you initiate state and once when you are using `this.setState`

Comment: yeah, but i don't want it to create a new graph on each render, but instead just create it once

Comment: @phantom so probably you have to look at `shouldComponentUpdate` method. if it is being called at initial state that you can handle it

Comment: i have created a question here in case someone else comes across the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722861/react-render-function-preventing-creating-new-canvas-element-on-each-invocation