# React render function preventing creating new canvas element on each time invoked - Charts.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am using React, Charts.js and react-chart.js.

I am making an API request which returns data that i am then visualizing. The problem I am having is that when the page initially loads it only displays one of the names, an then it renders again and the complete list of three names is shown. The problem is that a new graph is created each time the render function is invoked.

Does anyone know if there is a way to prevent a new graph being created each time, but instead to overwrite the previous graph that was created?

The canvas is being rendered twice, which I guess is expected the way the code is setup. On the first canvas element it just has one name, but then on the second canvas it contains all three names

Please see my code below:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      names: [],
      isLoaded: false
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      this.setState({
        names: data,
        isLoaded: true
      })
    }.bind(this));
  },
  render: function() {
    return ( < div > {
      this.state.isLoaded ? < Graph names = {
        this.state.names
      }
      /> : <div>Still Loading... </div >
    } < /div>)
  }
});

var Graph = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    var names = [];
    for (var i = this.props.artists.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      names.push(this.props.names[i].name);
    }

    var chartData = {
      labels: names,
      datasets: [{
        data: goals
      }, {
        data: predictions
      }]
    };

    return <LineChart data = {chartData} width = "600" height = "250" / >
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know... Ract is based on Virtual DOM... when it found a diff from virtual dom to real dom it patches .. So you got a re-render of that graph.. One way (I don't know if works) is to modify dom directly, using jquery...

Comment: Is the issue that it's duplicating the canvas or just rerendering it?

Comment: @BradBumbalough its rendering the canvas twice, which i guess is expected. But on the first canvas it just has one name, but then on the second canvas it contains all three names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not on React, but in ChartJS ... It's getting new information... but instead of updating ... it is inserting new canvas..

Try setting `redraw`.

From the docs https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs

> if data passed into the component changes, points will animate between
>   values using chart.js' .update(). If you want the chart destroyed and
>   redrawn on every change, pass in redraw as a prop. For example
>   `<LineChart data={this.state.chartData} redraw />`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like intended behaviour of React -- it will always rerender when the state changes. Your only options are to not bind your render to the state, or control if the update should get called. Without knowing what you're trying to accomplish, [the `react-chart` docs seem to indicate it won't rerender/redraw the initial Canvas element](https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs#example-usage).

If you want to manually control when the component will update, use the [**shouldComponentUpdate**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) method.

> Use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to let React know if a component's output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  // return true to continue with update, false to stop it
  return this.props.names.length == 0 && nextProps.names.length > 0
},
```

This could have side effects, such as if you are depending on `props.names` elsewhere and want that updated.