# json parsing error in reactjs map function does not work

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have json object as following :

```
{
  "id":1,"name":"Save the Queen - Corporate Carrom Tournament - 2018", "date":"28 may 2018","address":"Active Arena, Opposite Prestige Tech Park (Behind Croma) Outer Ring Road, Marathahalli, Kadubeesanahalli, Panathur,, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560103","banner":"https://preview.ibb.co/fTSnKn/badminton_blr.jpg", 


  "sports":[
      {"name":"Badminton","categoreis":[
        {"name":"Men Singles","fee":"600","gst":"108","formid":102,"form":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text"}]
        },
        {"name":"Men Doubles","fee":"1200","gst":"216","formid":103,"form":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Partner Name:","paramname":"partner_name","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Partner Email:","paramname":"partner_email","type":"text"}]
        },
        {"name":"Women Doubles","fee":"1200","gst":"216","formid":104,"form":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Partner Name:","paramname":"partner_name","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Partner Email:","paramname":"partner_email","type":"text"}]
        }
    ]
},

{"name":"Carrom","categoreis":[
        {"name":"Men Singles","fee":"399","gst":"72","formid":105,"form":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text"}]
        },
        {"name":"Men Doubles","fee":"799","gst":"144","formid":106,"form":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Partner Name:","paramname":"partner_name","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Partner Email:","paramname":"partner_email","type":"text"}]
        },
        {"name":"Women Doubles","fee":"799","gst":"144","formid":107,"form":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Partner Name:","paramname":"partner_name","type":"text"},
        {"label":"Partner Email:","paramname":"partner_email","type":"text"}]
        }
    ]
}

]}
```

But when I parse it inside render function like following I get "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". Can someone help me where am I making mistake?

```
this.state.tournament_detail.sports.map(
      function(sport,index){
        if(index==1){
          list1.push(<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href={"#"+index}>{sport.name}</a></li>);
        }else{
          list1.push(<li><a data-toggle="tab" href={"#"+index}>{sport.name}</a></li>);
        }
      }
    )
```

I have correctly verified that this.state.tournament_detail is correctly set to json as given above.

Full source code is this

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import style1 from './../css/main.css';
import RegisterWindow from './RegisterWindow.js';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import axios from 'axios';

var styles={
  container:{
  boxShadow: "0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)",
  textAlign: "center",
  margin:"auto",
  marginTop:"10px",
  borderRadius:"0.5vw",
  padding:"20px"
  },
  content : {
    top                   : '50%',
    left                  : '50%',
    right                 : 'auto',
    bottom                : 'auto',
    marginRight           : '-50%',
    transform             : 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
  }
}
Modal.setAppElement('#app')

export default class TournamentDetail extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     modalIsOpen: false,
     no_of_tickets:0,
     net_amount:0,
     tournament_detail:{}
   };

   this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
   this.afterOpenModal = this.afterOpenModal.bind(this);
   this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
   this.test=this.test.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
  //  alert('1');
    var self=this;
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/get-tournament-detail')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        self.setState({tournament_detail:response.data});
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  openModal() {
   this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
 }

 afterOpenModal() {
   // references are now sync'd and can be accessed.
   //this.subtitle.style.color = '#f00';
 }

 closeModal() {
   this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
 }

test(event,data){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(data);
  alert(event.target.value);
  alert('1');
  this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
}

  render(){
    var self=this;

    var list1=[];
    var list2=[];
    JSON.parse(this.state.tournament_detail).sports.map(
      function(sport,index){
        if(index==1){
          list1.push(<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href={"#"+index}>{sport.name}</a></li>);
        }else{
          list1.push(<li><a data-toggle="tab" href={"#"+index}>{sport.name}</a></li>);
        }
      }
    )

    return (
      <div class="container" style={styles.container}>

      <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen} onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal} onRequestClose={this.closeModal} contentLabel="Example Modal">
          <RegisterWindow close={this.test}/>
      </Modal>

        <div class="row" style={{borderBottomStyle:"ridge",borderBottomColor:"#0082c8",marginBottom:"10px",paddingBottom:"10px"}}>
          <div class="col-sm-8"><img style={{width:"100%",height:"100%"}} src={this.state.tournament_detail.banner}/></div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col" style={{borderBottomStyle:"solid",borderWidth: ".5px"}}>
                  <p style={{textAlign:"left"}}>{this.state.tournament_detail.name}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style={{marginTop:"10px"}}>
              <div class="col" style={{textAlign:"left"}}><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>  {this.state.tournament_detail.date}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style={{marginTop:"10px"}}>
              <div class="col" style={{textAlign:"left"}}><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>    {this.state.tournament_detail.address}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style={{marginTop:"20px"}}>
              <div class="col"><a href="#" style={{backgroundColor:"#ffc800",padding:"10px",borderRadius:"0.5vw",color:"#707070",textDecoration:"none"}} onClick={this.openModal} >Register</a> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <p style={{fontSize:"18px",float:"left",fontWeight:"500"}}>Pricing and Offers</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div  style={{borderStyle:"dotted",borderWidth: ".5px"}}>

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#badminton">Badminton</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tt">Table Tennis</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#carrom">Carrom</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
           <div id="badminton" class="tab-pane fade in active">

           <div className={style1.elem}>
               <div class="row"  style={{padding:"20px"}}>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <p style={{textAlign:"left"}}> Mens Singles</p>
                   <p style={{display:"block",textAlign:"left"}}> 399 +GST 72</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4"><p style={{float:"left"}}>471/-</p>
                   <a href="#" style={{backgroundColor:"#ffc800",padding:"10px", borderRadius:"0.5vw",color:"#707070",textDecoration:"none"}} onClick={this.openModal}>Register</a>
                 </div>

               </div>
           </div>
           <div style={{borderBottomStyle:"solid",borderWidth: "thin"}}></div>

           <div className={style1.elem}>
               <div class="row"  style={{padding:"20px"}}>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <p style={{textAlign:"left"}}> Mens Singles</p>
                   <p style={{display:"block",textAlign:"left"}}> 399 +GST 72</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4"><p style={{float:"left"}}>471/-</p>
                   <a href="#" style={{backgroundColor:"#ffc800",padding:"10px", borderRadius:"0.5vw",color:"#707070",textDecoration:"none"}}>Register</a>
                 </div>

               </div>
           </div>
           <div style={{borderBottomStyle:"solid",borderWidth: "thin"}}></div>

           <div className={style1.elem}>
               <div class="row"  style={{padding:"20px"}}>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <p style={{textAlign:"left"}}> Mens Singles</p>
                   <p style={{display:"block",textAlign:"left"}}> 399 +GST 72</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4"><p style={{float:"left"}}>471/-</p>
                   <a href="#" style={{backgroundColor:"#ffc800",padding:"10px", borderRadius:"0.5vw",color:"#707070",textDecoration:"none"}}>Register</a>
                 </div>
               </div>
           </div>


           </div>
           <div id="tt" class="tab-pane fade">

           <div className={style1.elem}>
               <div class="row"  style={{padding:"20px"}}>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <p style={{textAlign:"left"}}> Mens Singles</p>
                   <p style={{display:"block",textAlign:"left"}}> 499 +GST 72</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4"><p style={{float:"left"}}>471/-</p>
                   <a href="#" style={{backgroundColor:"#ffc800",padding:"10px", borderRadius:"0.5vw",color:"#707070",textDecoration:"none"}}>Register</a>
                 </div>

               </div>
           </div>
           <div style={{borderBottomStyle:"solid",borderWidth: "thin"}}></div>

           <div className={style1.elem}>
               <div class="row"  style={{padding:"20px"}}>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <p style={{textAlign:"left"}}> Mens Singles</p>
                   <p style={{display:"block",textAlign:"left"}}> 399 +GST 72</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4"><p style={{float:"left"}}>471/-</p>
                   <a href="#" style={{backgroundColor:"#ffc800",padding:"10px", borderRadius:"0.5vw",color:"#707070",textDecoration:"none"}}>Register</a>
                 </div>

               </div>
           </div>
           <div style={{borderBottomStyle:"solid",borderWidth: "thin"}}></div>

           <div className={style1.elem}>
               <div class="row"  style={{padding:"20px"}}>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <p style={{textAlign:"left"}}> Mens Singles</p>
                   <p style={{display:"block",textAlign:"left"}}> 399 +GST 72</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4"><p style={{float:"left"}}>471/-</p>
                   <a href="#" style={{backgroundColor:"#ffc800",padding:"10px", borderRadius:"0.5vw",color:"#707070",textDecoration:"none"}}>Register</a>
                 </div>
               </div>
           </div>

           </div>
           <div id="carrom" class="tab-pane fade">

           <div className={style1.elem}>
               <div class="row"  style={{padding:"20px"}}>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <p style={{textAlign:"left"}}> Mens Singles</p>
                   <p style={{display:"block",textAlign:"left"}}> 399 +GST 72</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4"><p style={{float:"left"}}>471/-</p>
                   <a href="#" style={{backgroundColor:"#ffc800",padding:"10px", borderRadius:"0.5vw",color:"#707070",textDecoration:"none"}}>Register</a>
                 </div>

               </div>
           </div>
           <div style={{borderBottomStyle:"solid",borderWidth: "thin"}}></div>

           <div className={style1.elem}>
               <div class="row"  style={{padding:"20px"}}>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <p style={{textAlign:"left"}}> Mens Singles</p>
                   <p style={{display:"block",textAlign:"left"}}> 399 +GST 72</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4"><p style={{float:"left"}}>471/-</p>
                   <a href="#" style={{backgroundColor:"#ffc800",padding:"10px", borderRadius:"0.5vw",color:"#707070",textDecoration:"none"}}>Register</a>
                 </div>

               </div>
           </div>
           <div style={{borderBottomStyle:"solid",borderWidth: "thin"}}></div>

           <div className={style1.elem}>
               <div class="row"  style={{padding:"20px"}}>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <p style={{textAlign:"left"}}> Mens Singles</p>
                   <p style={{display:"block",textAlign:"left"}}> 399 +GST 72</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4"><p style={{float:"left"}}>471/-</p>
                   <a href="#" style={{backgroundColor:"#ffc800",padding:"10px", borderRadius:"0.5vw",color:"#707070",textDecoration:"none"}}>Register</a>
                 </div>
               </div>
           </div>

           </div>
         </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <p style={{fontSize:"18px",float:"left",fontWeight:"500"}}>Detail</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div  style={{borderStyle:"dotted",borderWidth: ".5px"}}>
          <div style={{textAlign:"justify"}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.tournament_detail.detail}} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Hows your state looks like and where you're parsing it ?

Comment: added full source code. Kindly check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is related to async flow that you have e.g.

```
// can be componentWillMount
componentDidMount(){
  // fetch
  fetchMyDataFromServer()
    // initial state equal to {}
    .then(data => this.setState({tournament_detail: data}))
}
...
render(){
  // check if your state is not empty
  const { tournament_detail } = this.state
  return (
     <div>
       {Object.keys(tournament_detail).length > 0
         ? //... do what you want
         : // otherwise display a loading...
       }
     </div>
  )
}
```

Moreover [`Array.propotype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method returns a new array, so there are no needs to use `push` inside of it. Just replace your `push`s with `return` statements :)

[*Here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192621/reactjs-async-rendering-of-components?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) is a well explained answer that uses similar flow as you

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I am not sure, how will it solve the issue. The code below inside return is also using {this.state.tournament_detail}. If I remove the map code then that works fine and render well name, address, detail properties of the json object.

Comment: @hitesh while your data is fetching your state is empty and when you render data from states is says that `cannot read property of map from undefined`. So here you are comparing & making sure that the data is fetched & you can use map. First time when the state is empty user will see _loading_ and once it's fetched you will loop over your data. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

try `JSON.parse(this.state.tournament_detail).sports.map()` ?

If it works, do the `JSON.parse` where you are `setting state.tournament_detail` so you don't have to do it on every render. Then you can directly do `this.state.tournament_detail.sports.map()`.

Comment: Now after applying your changes, getting this error unexpected token o in JSON at position 1