# Async render ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, promise, asyncstorage

I have defined a method to load data from `AsyncStorage`

```
const loadFromAsyncStorage = async () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = await AsyncStorage.getItem('state');
    if (serializedState === null) return undefined;

    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    console.log(error.message);
    return undefined;
  }
};
```

Now I would like to persist the state returned into my redux as below

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const persistedState = loadFromAsyncStorage();

    persistedState.then(x => {
      // ??
    });

    const store = createStore(
      reducers, 
      persistedState, 
      applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
    );

    store.subscribe(() => saveToAsyncStorage(store.getState()));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

As above, `persistedState` will be a `Promise` returned by `loadFromAsyncStorage()` and the value can only be accessed if I chain `.then()` or adding a keyword `await` in front of `loadFromAsyncStorage()` method. I'm not sure how to achieve it in a render method as I can't make the `render` method async

Comment: Are you sure you want to `createStore` inside the `render` method? It should be outside.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192621/reactjs-async-rendering-of-components

Comment: I think that, you can dispatch inside of then and your createStore must be outside of render.

Comment: @HardikModha: Do you mind to show me how moving the `createStore` out of render method can be working in my example?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) for this problem.

You simply need to create a separate store entry for all the app data, and redux-persist handle the persistence of those entries automatically to asyncStorage.

Full working example from [Alexander Wolf](https://github.com/AWolf81) is on this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o95yl1z6pz).