# How to return axios value to a variable in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, request-promise

I call a function inside react render with this code

```
    {this.getChar({char})}
```

I have a function to return value from axios

```
    getChar(url){
        var res = ''
        axios.get(url).then( datas => {
                res = datas.name
                console.log(datas.name)  
        });
        return res
    }
```

If i run the getchar function, in my console will display string as i want, but how to send that string to 'res' variable so i can return a string from the getChar function ?

In example, if i run

```
    var url = 'https://some/url/'
```

and i call getchar function

```
    getChar(url)
```

it will display

```
    result
```

Thanks for help

Comment: This question will almost certainly get closed as a duplicate, as variants of this question get asked at least once a day. Where you have res = datas.name, use something like `this.setState({res: datas.name})`. And then render `this.state.res`. Call this.getChar() inside the render function before `return`, or somewhere else appropriate.

Comment: First off, you have timing problems in your getChar function. It will return res long before axios.get(...) completes. Secondly this gets answered a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49890315/3236706

Comment: Read on `asynchronous` programming and working of `Promises` in JS