# React JSON is undefined

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks, undefined

I'm fetching this JSON from an API:

```
{
  "data": {
    "email": "test@tre.com",
    "inserted_at": "2021-03-30T15:37:06",
    "links": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "My link title",
        "url": "http://google.com"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "My Youube title",
        "url": "http://youtube.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm fetching it this way using Hooks:

```
export default function Notes() {
  const [json, setJSON] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/users/1", {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        // console.log(data);
        setJSON(json);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, [setJSON]);
```

Then I try to show it like this:

```
return (
    <>
      <div className="content">
          {JSON.stringify(json)}
          <h1>{json.email}</h1>
</div>
</>
);
```

The line `{JSON.stringify(json)}` shows the JSON.

But the line `<h1>{json.email}</h1>` doesn't show anything.

**I don't know why that happens and how can I access my variables.**

Thanks . I appreciate any help

Comment: Typo: You forgot the `data.` part of the structure.

Comment: Yes, but then it says that json.data is undefined. I don't know why. I typed json.data.email

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs async rendering of components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192621/reactjs-async-rendering-of-components) While it uses a class component, the problem/solution are the same. Fetching is async so the `data` is undefined until it's available, so you must handle that state (loading) before using the data.

Comment: Try doing  {json && <h1>{json.email}</h1>}

Comment: Not really (:  I'm not working with Ajax

Comment: @manuel.menendez you're working with asynchronous data fetching, it doesn't matter what is used to fetch the data.

Comment: @ArrowHead same problem. json.data is undefined

Comment: @EmileBergeron ok, but the JSON.stringify works cause it's reading it. Then why the line below doesn't work? I'm completely lost

Comment: Is your data an array or an object? Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the data in the form of an array or an object?

You defined the initial state as and array ad hence you cannot do

```
// you can't do json.email if you expect the response as and array


 const [json, setJSON] = useState([]);
```

change it to

```
 const [json, setJSON] = useState({});
```

if it is an object. Then in the template do

```
{json.data && <h1>{json.data.email}</h1>}
```

Comment: According to the data in the question, it's probably closer to `json.data.email`, and I wouldn't initialize the state with an object (nor an array), otherwise, the condition becomes useless. Just `useState()` would be enough to prevent rendering until the data is received.

Comment: yes, you're right. I had that wrong. but still I'm receiving json.data is undefined. I'm completely lost

Comment: emile.bergeron, you got it. Guys thanks. How can I give you the SOLVED?

Comment: Yes accepting this answer would be fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1>{json.data && json.data.email}</h1>
```

instead of

```
<h1>{json.email}</h1>
```